# need help in finding sbt assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am going through a course on sbt and found the below line of code in assembly.sbt file "addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")". This is set by tutor as per his sbt version installed and I came to know that we need to change assembly value(0.14.3) as per our installed sbt version. I have installed sbt 1.2.7 for windows.
Can someone help in getting the assembly value that I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the below link to find the available versions of abt-assembly.

https://bintray.com/eed3si9n/sbt-plugins/sbt-assembly

As per my understanding, you should go with the latest version of abt-assembly which is 0.14.9.

Your tutor is using some older versions which might not be supported in the latest version being used by you.